# Auto login with spring security

Tags: java, servlets, spring-security

I have an application which uses spring-security. In my signup process, a new user entity gets persisted with the HASHED password, an email containing an activation token is the sent to the user. Clicking on this token directs the user to a UserActivationServlet which looks up the user by the token, activates the user and redirects them to the application. I would like to automatically log the user into the application and have included this method in my servlet to do this

```
    private void authenticateUserAndSetSession(HttpServletRequest request, User u) {
    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken token = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
            u.getUsername(), u.getPassword()); //PROBLEM: THIS PASSWORD IS HASHED

    // generate session if one doesn't exist
    request.getSession();

    token.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetails(request));
    Authentication authenticatedUser = authenticationManager.authenticate(token);

    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authenticatedUser);
    request.getSession().setAttribute(HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT_KEY,
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext());
}
```

The problem here is that that the password field on the User entity has been hashed when it was created. So the only other option I can think of is to pass the unhashed password as a request parameter to the servelet (nasty!)

Have I missed something, is there another way of pre-authenticating the user?

Thanks

Comment: I was being stupid here, the user has clicked on the activation link and we have looked him up so clearly we have a valid user, so there is no need to re-authenticate him with the authenticationManager and so no need to use credentials when creating the Token, just create it as follows: PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken token = new PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken(
                p, null, p.getAuthorities());

Comment: another similar question (and answer) can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12057327/26510

Comment: @ClintonBosch You can write the comment as an answer and accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The user has clicked on the activation link and we have looked him up so clearly we have a valid user, so there is no need to re-authenticate him with the `authenticationManager` and so no need to use credentials when creating the Token, just create it as follows:

```
PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken token = new PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken( p, null, p.getAuthorities());
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly [SOA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service-oriented_architecture) can help you.

You don't need to make a redirect to the login page, but rather call the service that logs the user in. Any login related logic residing in a controller (or somewhere above the service layer) should be moved 'down' and used by your servlet.

The service could look something like:

```
public interface LoginService {
    // this will be called from the login page
    public void login(String username, String hashedPass);

    // this will only be visible to other services
    // you can secure it with AOP and Spring security's method security
    public void login(String username);
}
```

Then you can call `loginService.login(username);` from your servlet.

Or in your exact case pass your token without a password:

```
loginService.login(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(u.getUsername(), ""));
```